# Circle zero size in d3 svg angular 2 typescript

Tags: html, css, typescript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to plot a simple line graph using d3 in Angular2 typescript, Here is my code,

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1><div class="chart" #chart></div>`,
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit { 
 @ViewChild('chart') private chartContainer: ElementRef;
 @Input() private data: Array<any>;
 private margin: any = { top: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20, right: 20};
 private chart: any;
 private width: number;
 private height: number;
 private xScale: any;
 private yScale: any;
 private colors: any;
 private xAxis: any;
 private yAxis: any;  
 name = 'Angular';

ngOnInit() {
 this.generateData();
 this.createChart();
 if (this.data) {
     this.updateChart();
 }
}
```

Here I generated random data

```
generateData() {
  this.data = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < (8 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)); i++) {
      this.data.push([
          `Index ${i}`,
          Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
      ]);
  }
}
```

Here I create X and Y axis for the line,

```
 createChart() {

   let element = this.chartContainer.nativeElement;
   let svg = d3.select(element).append('svg');

   svg.attr('width', element.offsetWidth)
   .attr('height', element.offsetHeight);

  this.width = this.chartContainer.nativeElement.offsetWidth - 
  this.margin.left - this.margin.right;
  this.height = this.chartContainer.nativeElement.offsetHeight - 
  this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;

  // chart plot area
  this.chart = svg;

  // define X & Y domains
  let xDomain = this.data.map(d => d[0]);
  let yDomain = [0, d3.max(this.data, (d: any) => {return d[1]})];

 // create scales
 this.xScale = d3.scaleBand().padding(0.1).domain(xDomain).rangeRound([0, this.width]);
 this.yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain(yDomain).range([this.height, 0]);

// bar colors
 this.colors = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, this.data.length]).range(<any[]>['red', 'blue']);

// x & y axis
 this.xAxis = svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis axis-x')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${this.margin.left}, ${this.margin.top + this.height})`)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(this.xScale));
this.yAxis = svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis axis-y')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${this.margin.left}, ${this.margin.top})`)
    .call(d3.axisLeft(this.yScale));
}
```

Here I tried to add plots (as circle) to the places where, it has to be plotted,
everything (plot position,count) is fine, But the width and height is always zero, hence not showing up in the UI

```
    updateChart() {

        this.chart = this.chart.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'dots')
        .attr('transform', `translate(${this.margin.left}, ${this.margin.top})`);

        // update scales & axis
        this.xScale.domain(this.data.map(d => d[0]));
        this.yScale.domain([0, d3.max(this.data, (d:any) => {return d[1]})]);
        this.colors.domain([0, this.data.length]);
        this.xAxis.transition().call(d3.axisBottom(this.xScale));
        this.yAxis.transition().call(d3.axisLeft(this.yScale));

        let update = this.chart.selectAll('.dot')
            .data(this.data);

        update.exit().remove();

        update
            .enter()
            .append('circle')
            .attr('class', 'dot')
            .attr('cx', (d : any) => {return this.xScale(d[0])})
            .attr('cy', (d:any) =>{return this.yScale(d[1])})
            .style('fill', (d:any, i:any) => { console.log(d); return this.colors(i)});
    }
```

}

As in the below image, all the plots are there, but since g is of zero height and width, they are always zero,

whereas If I replace them with 'rect' instead of 'circle' with height and width, it is showing up. I m sure some styling missing for those elements, but not sure what they are, Please give suggestions or fix

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding the `radius` attribute to the `circle`?

Comment: inclusion of radius works,sorry, such a silly mistake!

Comment: FWIW, you said that *"since g is of zero height and width, they are always zero"*... g elements have no height or width. They auto size to their contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the radii of the circles, otherwise it defaults to zero (actually, `null`):

```
update.enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('class', 'dot')
    .attr("r", someValue)//set the radius here
    .attr('cx', (d : any) => {return this.xScale(d[0])})
    .attr('cy', (d:any) =>{return this.yScale(d[1])})
    .style('fill', (d:any, i:any) => { console.log(d); return this.colors(i)});
```